# Read XML tree like reading custom section in app.config

Tags: c#, .net, xml, .net-4.6

I have a custom section in app.config that I want to move to its own resource file in order to hide it from the application user.

The custom section *applicationMenu* defines a menu structure and is read like this:

```
AppMenu appMenu = 
     System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("applicationMenu") as AppMenu;
```

Now I'm looking for a class which is also able to read the whole *applicationMenu* tree into an `object` in order to re-use my `AppMenu` class.

I had a look at the `System.Configuration.Configuration` class but the returned object of the method `GetSection("applicationMenu")` is unusable for my purpose:

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap customConfigFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
customConfigFileMap.ExeConfigFilename = "applicationMenu.xml";
Configuration customConfig =
    ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(customConfigFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

// compile error, cannot convert:
AppMenu appMenu = customConfig.GetSection("applicationMenu") as AppMenu;
```

Comment: If you're moving a whole custom section into its own file, why use the configuration API at all? You can just read and deserialize the XML in any way you please (`XElement`, `XmlSerializer`, any number of third-party libraries).

Comment: Yes, indeed. I didn't figure out that `ConfigurationManager.GetSection(..)` does a deserialization anyway!